# link time warning about VPF registers

Tags: gcc, arm, cortex-m

I'm trying to port a project from Cortex M0 to Cortex M4 with hardware floating point extension, the new target soc is [nRF52832](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Low-power-short-range-wireless/nRF52832).

The error I am getting from the linker is the following

```
arm-unknown-eabi/bin/ld: error: x.o uses VFP register arguments, firmware does not
```

where firmware is the name of the output file fro the linker.

This is an issue with the arm ABI for floating point, I want to use the FPU as it is requested by
the FreeRTOS port I want to use but I don't get how to tweak my linker flags to make it possible.

This is the set of linker flags I'm currently using

```
-L/path/to/nrfx/mdk
-Wl, --no-undefined
-Wl,--as-needed -march=armv7e-m+fp -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mabi=aapcs
-Wl, --start-group support/libs/libQRCode.a support/libs/libSPIFFS.a
-Wl, --no-undefined
-Wl, --as-needed
-Wl, --gc-sections --specs=nosys.specs -T/path/to/linker_script.ld /toolchain/path/to/lib/libm.a
-Wl, --end-group
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-mfloat-abi` flag is a compiler-only flag, so there is no point in passing it to the linker.

In order to be able to build a firmware image that uses the hard-float ABI, all object files passed to the linker must be compiled to use that ABI. You issue is most likely due to the fact that you are passing to the linker one or more object files compiled with the soft-float ABI instead; for example, the `/toolchain/path/to/lib/libm.a` file path in your linker command line looks suspicious, you should use the hard-float version of libm.a, which you will likely find in the `hard/` sub-folder of your toolchain library path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the hints about where to find the hard-float version of libm.a; right now I can't confirm this is the cause but when I'll be able to recompile my toolchain for hard float I'll confirm

Comment: I recompiled my toolchain to support multilib and this the error is gone, I'm not sure if GCC is automatically deciding which `libm.a` to use but I'm only seeing one under `/opt/toolchain/arm-none-eabi/arm-none-eabi/lib/libm.a` while there are multiple directories for *hard* and *soft* variants in libgcc.